'pg' package TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
When I try to run then function on it, it will return this error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
at Object.\<anonymous\> (/app/src/index.js:52:2)
at Module.\_compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1546:14)
at Module.\_extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1691:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1317:32)
at Module.\_load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1127:12)
^

const { Client } = require('pg');

const PG_USER = 'root';
const PG_PASSWORD = 'example';
const PG_HOST = 'postgres';
const PG_PORT = '5432';
const PG_URI = `postgresql://${PG_USER}:${PG_PASSWORD}@${PG_HOST}:${PG_PORT}`;

const client =  new Client({
  connectionString: PG_URI,
});

client.connect(PG_URI)
  .then( () =>console.log('connect to postgresdb...'))
  .catch((err)=>console.log('failed connect to postgresdb:' ,err))                                                                                                            


version:  10.8.1

"pg": "^8.12.0"

I think you need to remove PG_URI from your client.connect method call. You've already provided PG_URI when you instantiated Client. As far as I can tell, client.connect doesn't take any arguments and is used just to initiate the connection to your database.
Edit: Per the comment below, you can pass a callback but then it doesn’t return a promise.

pg.connect can take an argument ... a callback ... and if an argument is supplied, it doesn't return a Promise - which explains the error perfectly, since presumably it returns undefined when an argument is present, and undefined famously has no .then method

@mhborthwick
if i remove PG-URI from client.connect call ,
it change the error to failed connect to
postgresdb: Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.18.0.2:5432
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1605:16) {
errno: -113,
code: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '172.18.0.2',
port: 5432
}

@Jaromanda , so what should i do ?

@mohamedmoniem EXACTLY what this answer tells you to do ¯\(ツ)/¯

Thanks @Jaromanda - edited my answer per your comment.

@mohamedmoniem The error you're seeing might be due to your database not running on port 5432 or an issue with your connection string. If you see that your database is running, I would double-check your connection string. I found this thread with some info on the correct format.
